# Adapter of collection - omit T that depends on underlying collection

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, c++14, virtual-functions

I am trying to create an adapter of a custom collection `MyArray<T>`.
For simplicity, the adapter `Adapter` does only one thing : cast the return result of `MyArray<T>::get`.

*(In real case, `MyArray` and `Adapter` are very complex database manipulators.)*

### Version 1

Here is the first version, it works.  ([demo](http://ideone.com/GxnifV))

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>class MyArray{
    public: T* database[20];   
    public: T* get(int index){return database[index];} //<-important
    public: void set(int index,T* t){database[index]=t;} 
};
template<class T,class T2> class Adapter{
    public: MyArray<T>* underlying;
    public: void setUnderlying(MyArray<T>* pUnder){underlying=pUnder;}
    public: T2* get(int index){return static_cast<T2*>(underlying->get(index));}
    //^ "Adapter::get()" is encapsulating "MyArray::get()"
};
class B{};
class C:public B{}; 
class D:public C{};

int main() {
    MyArray<B> bs;
    bs.set(0,new C());  //some can be new D()
    //About the Adapter<C>, user is the one who sure that "bs" elements are "C*"-castable.
    Adapter<B,C> cs;       //<-- #1 need improve
    cs.setUnderlying(&bs); //<-- assign MyArray* to adapter
    C* c=cs.get(0);
    return 0;
}
```

### Version 2

Then, I want to sacrifice performance for readability and convenience. (`#1`)
**Objective:** Reduce amounts of template parameters of  from 2 (`Adapter<B,C>`) to 1 (`Adapter<C>`).

Here is my work so far.  It is compilable but should crash in some cases:-

```
class MyArrayBase{  //<--- new class
     public: virtual void* get(int index)=0;
};
template<class T>class MyArray : public MyArrayBase{
    public: T* database[20];
    public: T* get(int index){return database[index];}
    public: void set(int index,T* t){database[index]=t;}
};
template<class T2> class Adapter{
    public: MyArrayBase* underlying;  //<--- more abstraction 
    public: void setUnderlying(MyArrayBase* pUnder){underlying=pUnder;}
    public: T2* get(int index){return static_cast<T2*>(underlying->get(index));}   //#wrong
};
class B{};
class C:public B{};

int main() {
    MyArray<B> bs;
    bs.set(0,new C()); 
    Adapter<C> cs;   //<--- Yes! 1 template argument.
    cs.setUnderlying(&bs);
    C* c=cs.get(0);
    std::cout<<"hi"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**The reason that it is wrong :-**
At the `#wrong`, `void*` (underlying `B*`) is `static_cast` to `C*`.
Here is the [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d5e04d28e33837b) shows that it is wrong.    (print 0 instead of 5)

### Question

How to improve my first version of code to make `Adapter` have less template parameter?

**Criteria :-**

- Don't use function pointer.
  I feel it is possible with function pointer or `std::function`, but it seems to be a hack.
  I also want to know if it is possible **without** using it.
- Overhead should not be (roughly) worse than a single virtual calling (v-table) as in Version 2.
- A single instance of `Adapter<C>::setUnderlying` must be able to accept any `MyArray<X>*` when it makes sense to call `static_cast<C*>(X*)`.
- `MyArray` and `Adapter` are library class.  It doesn't have any knowledge about the type `T` or `T2`.
  For example, I can't replace `void*` in `class MyArrayBase` with `B*`.

**Light criteria :-**

- I prefer a solution using virtual function.
- It would be ideal if there is no virtual-cost, but I don't think it is possible.

Comment: One way might be using changing the `T* get` in `MyArray` to a `void*` so the `get` actually gets used.

Comment: @Winestone It seems to be an interesting idea.  I have never thought about it.  I might try too hard to avoid `void*`.  Thank.

Comment: Doesn't work though, only gets rid of the warnings.

Comment: I think your idea should work if `void*` is actually kept like `void* database[20];`.  However, there would be another problem for more complex hierarchy e.g. after call `set(0,D*)` (suppose `D` derived from `C`).  In other words, the `void*` in `void* database[20];` much actually be exactly `C*`.

Comment: if you can derive all `B`'s from one base class which is polymorphic (has something `virtual` in it, I think you can use `dynamic_cast` to do it. Edit: Something like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b98e26544dbd4ab

Comment: @Winestone Agree, `static_cast` also works.  By the way, it is inelegant.  There will be the strange requirement that I have to tell users (element must derived from a certain class - `Dummy`).  This lowers quality/usability  of library (at least a little).

Comment: Is it ok if you pass `bs` to `cs` in the constructor of `cs`? Then you can use templates to deduce the 2nd template argument. You could also have `Adapter<T2>` and then have `AdapterImpl<T2, T>` inherit from that and implement virtual functions for converting from `T` to `T2` and then declare a `Adapter<C>* cs = new AdapterImpl<C, B>();`.

Comment: @Winestone No, I can't.  A single instance of `Adapter<C>` should support both `MyArray<C> `and `MyArray<B>`, because I will `setUnderlying(MyArray*)` later at run time. .... The second half is interesting, but I doubt I will pay the virtual-cost twice to solve only 1 problem. (not sure, will investigate more)   Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some kind of wrapper that wraps the container, typically:

```
// Here T = T2, you want a virtual function that already give you the right type
template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    virtual T* get(int index) const = 0;
};

// The real wrapper: It can give you T2 (To) but keep information
// about the original type since it is templated on Container
template <class To, class Container>
class WrapperContainer: public Wrapper<To> {
    Container *cont_;
public:  
    WrapperContainer(Container *cont) : cont_(cont) { }
    virtual To* get(int index) const override {
        return static_cast<To*>(cont_->get(index));
    }
};
```

The wrapper is the middle-guy between your `Adapter` that only knows the `To` type (the type you want to convert to) and your `MyArray` that only knows the `From` type (the type you want to convert from) - The `WrapperContainer` knows both, so it can safely convert from one to the other when it is possible.

The final `Adapter`:

```
template<class T2> 
class Adapter {
    std::unique_ptr<Wrapper<T2>> w_; 
public:

    template <typename Container>
    void setUnderlying(Container *cont) {
        w_ = std::unique_ptr<Wrapper<T2>>(new WrapperContainer<T2, Container>(cont));
    }

    T2* get(int index)  {
        return w_->get(index);
    }
};
```

Using this you do not want a base class for `MyArray` since you need `setUnderlying` to deduce the type `B` from `MyArray<B>`:

```
// No more need for a base class
template<class T>
class MyArray {
    T* database[20];
public: 
    T* get(int index){return database[index];}
    void set(int index,T* t){database[index]=t;}
};
```

The important change from your code is actually this line:

```
return static_cast<To*>(cont_->get(index));
```

The type of `cont_->get(index)` is `B*` (in this example) and not `void*`, which makes the conversion work. This also prevents using `setUnderlying` with array of non-compatible type (try to uncomment the line `cs.setUnderlying(&as);` in the code below).

You can test it here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/116305ec5f18b673

Comment: Thank. I don't expect that someone will find answer to this hard question! ....   With some work (e.g. custom allocator / `char[]`), the (heap) indirection at `std::unique_ptr` cost can also be removed completely, right?

Comment: @javaLover This could be a bit more complicated because you would need to allocate the space for a `WrapperContainer` which can be dependent of the `Container`, I would have to check the standard to see if there is a way to guarantee a maximum space for any `WrapperContainer`. At first, I would say that if you reserve space for `WrapperContainer` with `Container = void` (specialization to avoid compilation issue), you should have guaranteed space for every container, but I am really not 100% sure.

Comment: The more I read your solution, the more I like it. It is really fascinating. The idea to virtual at `Adapter` instead of `MyArray` is so creative. How can I improve myself to be half as good as you? Did you read any specific book or is it experience?